# Veracrypt: rsync syncs all files every time

Tags: linux, rsync, veracrypt

I try to backup my files with rsync on a HDD that I encrypted with Veracrypt.

But the problem is that it copies **all** files every time.

That is my command:

`rsync -av --delete "$source/" "$hdd/dest/"`

I also tried `-t` and `-u`, didn't make a difference.

`--ignore-existing` worked in so far that it didn't copy the same files every time, but it also ignored changes in documents.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time-stamps may be off by an amount that makes files seem
different, so all are copied.

Use the following `rsync` parameter to increase time granularity:

> **--modify-window**
>
> When comparing two timestamps, rsync treats the timestamps as being
> equal if they differ by no more than the modify-window value. This is
> normally 0 (for an exact match), but you may find it useful to set
> this to a larger value in some situations. In particular, when
> transferring to or from an MS Windows FAT filesystem (which represents
> times with a 2-second resolution), --modify-window=1 is useful
> (allowing times to differ by up to 1 second).

Try for example `--modify-window=2`.

Comment: Very good solution, it worked! Thanks!